# Transitivity of smooth submanifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I was reading through Guillemin and Pollack and was having trouble verifying this for myself. Given $M \subset N$ and $N \subset P$, where $M$ is a submanifold of $N$, and $N$ a submanifold of $P$, how would one show that $M$ is also a submanifold of $P$?

Comment: This should follow from the more general principle that a composition of embeddings is also an embedding.

Comment: Is there a simple way to do it using the definition of smooth submanifolds through coordinate charts directly

Comment: Ah, well, you didn't use the word smooth at first! I was speaking to the topological case. But yes you can do it. The point is that $M\subset N$ looks locally like $\mathbb R^m\subset\mathbb R^n$ and $N\subset P$ looks locally like $\mathbb R^n\subset \mathbb R^p$. Now use the induced inclusion $\mathbb R^m\subset\mathbb R^p$ to see that $M\subset P$ looks locally like $\mathbb R^m\subset\mathbb R^p$.

Comment: How exactly would I do that using the direct definition that if $M$ is a submanifold of $N$, then $\forall x \in M,  \exists U $ open in $N$ containing $x$ and $\exists$ an $h : U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $h(U \cap \mathbb{R}^{m}) = h(U) \cap \mathbb{R}^{m}$ where we have $dim(M) = m, dim(N) = n$. Sorry, but I'm just having trouble establishing this relation between the first and third objects in the inclusion.

Comment: Take your $h\colon U\to\mathbb R^n$ and compose it with the inclusion $\mathbb R^n\subset \mathbb R^p$ to get a map $\hat{h}\colon U\to \mathbb R^p$.